# Does Hibernate (JPA) allow to map custom columns (i.e. Aliased columns)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having simple entity with few properties as shown in image.
[image]

Query as follows

```
select *,concat(current_date - cre_dte::date)  as _days_ago
from test."general" 
where (current_date - cre_dte::date)=7 or (current_date - cre_dte::date)<11
```

My Entity is

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "general", schema = "test")
public class GeneralEntity implements Serializable {
 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2343243243242432341L;
    
    /**
     * id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
 
    /**
     * loadNumber
     */
    @Column(name="load_number")
    private String loadNumber;
    
    /**
     * createdDate
     */
    @Column(name="cre_dte")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Formula(value = "_days_ago")
    private String _daysAgo;
}
```

I am trying to map entities to store `_days_ago` from my native query to pojo. for that I modified pojo to add @Formula. but seems like does not mapping this alias to my property. In my JPA interface my method is like below

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "select *, concat(current_date - cre_dte::date)  as _days_ago  from general where (current_date - cre_dte::date)=7 or (current_date - cre_dte::date)<11")
public List<GeneralEntity> getFewDaysAgo() throws Exception;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Formula` for this purpose like:

```
public class GeneralEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Formula("current_date - cre_dte::date")
    Integer daysAgo;
}
```

but I generally don't recommend that as that will be executed every time you fetch a GeneralEntity entity.

Usually this is best handled by using a custom DTO projection for this use case. You could use something like the following:

```
class GeneralEntityDto {
    Long id;
    String loadNumber;
    Date createdDate;
    String daysAgo;
    // constructor + getters
}
```

and a query like this:

```
@Query("select new com.mycompany.package.GeneralEntityDto(g.id, g.loadNumber, g.createdDate, concat(current_date - cast(g.createdDate as date)) from GeneralEntity where (current_date - cast(g.createdDate as date))=7 or (current_date - cast(g.createdDate as date))<11")
public List<GeneralEntityDto> getFewDaysAgo();
```

If you have more complex needs like the need to map collections, you should give [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) a shot.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(GeneralEntity.class)
public interface GeneralEntityDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getLoadNumber();
    Date getCreatedDate();
    @Mapping("DAY_DIFF(CAST_DATE(createdDate), current_date)")
    String getDaysAgo();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`GeneralEntityDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, GeneralEntityDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
public default List<GeneralEntityDto> getFewDaysAgo() {
    return findAll((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Expression e = criteriaBuilder.function("DAY_DIFF", root.get(createdDate).as(java.sql.Date.class), criteriaBuilder.currentDate());
        return criteriaBuilder.or(
            criteriaBuilder.equal(e, criteriaBuilder.literal(7)), 
            criteriaBuilder.lessThan(e, criteriaBuilder.literal(1))
        );
    });
}

public List<GeneralEntityDto> findAll(Specification s);
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, by adding constructor based it works for me.